# Proving that this group is Abelian via inverse property

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Prove that a group G is Abelian If and Only If 
$\left ( ab \right )^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ for all a and b in G

Proving first the If condition:

$\left ( ab \right )\left ( ab \right )^{-1}=\left ( ab \right )\left ( a^{-1}b^{-1} \right )$
we require commutativity here in order to satisfy $\left ( ab \right )\left ( ab \right )^{-1}=e$
so,
$\left ( ab \right )\left ( a^{-1}b^{-1} \right )=ab\left ( b^{-1}a^{-1} \right )=a\left ( bb^{-1} \right )a^{-1}=aea^{-1}=aa^{-1}=e
$

Now, the Only If condition:

Because G is Abelian, we have 
$a\circ b=b\circ a  
\forall a,b \in G$

We have 
$\left ( ab \right )\left (ab  \right )^{-1}=\left ( ab \right )\left ( b^{-1}a^{-1} \right )=a\left ( bb^{-1} \right )a^{-1}=aea^{-1}=aa^{-1}=e$

Is this proof done correctly? My concern is with the 'If' condition.

Comment: Apart from asserting that it must commute in order for the condition to be satisfied, I am unable to come up with an alternate explanation@Leo

Comment: It appears that there  are 3 identical answers :D. The problem is that your argument has the following structure: We want to prove X, I don't see any option but X, therefore X. But you have to argue why there are no other options but X.

Comment: @Leo It is in fact a fallacy for me to have assert that argument.

Comment: Yeah, since you assert the conclusion :D

Comment: @Leo Not that I was expecting to go scot free, though.

Comment: Well it is important that you see difference between a good and a bad proof. So for that you are to be commended.

Comment: Your only if part is also incorrect. You show that $(ab)(ab)^{-1} = e$. But this is true in *any* group! You need to show that $(ab)(a^{-1}b^{-1}) = e$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the if condition: 
$$e=ab(ab)^{-1}= (ab)(a^{-1}b^{-1})$$
Now multiply both sides with $ba$. You get
$$eba =ba =ab.$$
For the only if just use the identity:
$$(ab)^{-1}= b^{-1}a^{-1}$$ and now apply commutativity.

Answer (score 2):

All the ideas are there. The problem is the way you have written out the proof. For example, the statement "we require commutativity here..." doesn't justify why you need it, and it isn't entirely clear what you're trying to show with the argument that follows.

Here is how I would write out a solution (to the if statement), but I'll stress again that you have all the ideas already!

Suppose that for all $a,b\in G$ we have $(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$. Then for any $a,b\in G$, we have $$e = (ab)(ab)^{-1} = (ab)(a^{-1}b^{-1}).$$

Multiplying on the right by $ba$, we see that
$$ba =(ab)(a^{-1}b^{-1})ba = ab,$$so $ab = ba $. Hence $G$ is abelian.

Comment: I admit the "we require..." part is fuzzy. I was thinking along the line of 'x must be true, for if it were not...then...'

Comment: You definitely had the right idea! But one of the most important parts of proving something is actually writing out the proof!  Your proof should clearly indicate how you get from your assumption (that $(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$ for all $a,b$) to your conclusion (that $G$ is abelian)

Comment: On the 'only if' part, 
Since G is Abelian, can I not assert commutativity?

Comment: You can and must assert commutativity. However, in your proof, you have at no point used the property that $ab = ba$.

Comment: Would $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ not be valid?

Comment: No. You cannot write down the statement $(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$ because that is what you are trying to prove. You can however say that $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$ (in any group) and that $b^{-1}a^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$ since $G$ is abelian. Writing $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$ would be lazy but valid. The difference in the order is crucial.

Comment: Ok. I used the socks and shoe property, and, the left and right cancellation property for the only if condition and indeed arrived at the requirement $(ab)^{-1}=(a^{-1}b^{-1})$

Answer (score 1):

- If

$ba=(a^{-1}b^{-1})^{-1}=(b^{-1}a^{-1})^{-1}=ab$

The second equality is essential.

- Only if

$(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$

The second equality is essential.